# How to route 600 waypoints?

Tags: routes, here-api, here-maps-rest

IM using the free version 6 API and, as I know, I cant send more than 120 without traffic and 50 with traffic, and I think this is because I must send the waypoint list in the URL.
Is there a way to send 600 waypoint to get a Route?
Thanks

Comment: HERE has so many different APIs, can you please be more specific which API you are using? And it would be nice if you could explain in more detail what do you mean by "600 waypoints" routing, what is your use case? Are you talking about one route of one vehicle with 600 consecutive intermediary stops until it reaches its final destination?

Comment: This is the API Im using and yes, on single truck need to start, go to 600 consecutive different Address and final destination.

Comment: OK, so you are using Routing API. Please note that you have shared your private API key in your comment, it is strongly recommended to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the sequence/order of the intermediary stops (i.e. you know that your vehicle has to stop firstly to waypoint A and then to waypoint B, etc) you can just break down your request to multiple consecutive requests in a linear fashion.

If you don't know the sequence of your waypoints, then the `Waypoints Sequence` endpoint of the Fleet Telematics API will do the trick https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-simple-car.html
But in this case there is no way to avoid the limit of waypoints: `The maximum number of waypoints including the start point and end point is 120 without traffic and 50 with traffic`.

Comment: I don't know the sequence of your waypoints, that what I need the API do for me, 120 points is very poor, our trucks delives 400 or more each day. Another problem is the way you design the API, having to send the waypoint list trough the URL is not good, there are a limit in the url size and you use the parameter "waypoinX" which takes meny characters, hard to send 120 points.

Comment: HERE's Tour Planning API support 250 points, but you can access this API only with Pro Plan ($449/month).

Comment: Just to be clear, you have 1 truck delivering to 400 points in a single day? Or do you mean that the WHOLE fleet (multiple trucks) deliver altogether to 400points per day?

Comment: 12 trucks delivering up to 600 points in a single day, yes. 7200 point a day.

Comment: OK, this is a very extreme corner case, definitely not supported by HERE APIs. 600 points within a single day is almost impossible. Even if a truck could arrive to the next destination within only 2 minutes, this would require a 20 hours non-stop shift to complete 600 destinations within one day. I am very curious to understand what kind of trucks are these, what do they transport?

Comment: We can have 10 points in the same block, so the truck stops only in one corner of the block and from there workers serve the 10 addresses of the block. This are box of cosmetics send to Avon resellers.

Comment: OK, so maybe one idea is for you to group the 10 points within one block into only one point when you are calling the API.

Comment: I had this Idea but ... how to do it? I dont have the block corners coordinates of each block in each city of my country.